# Add static text to post URLs

Tags: posts, url-rewriting

I have 2 pages on my site which include blog posts (real site is pw protected):

https://example.com/blog/

https://example.com/news/

All blog and news articles should have a URL that begins with https://example.com/my-blog/.

Example: https://example.com/my-blog/this-is-the-article-name

So, what I need to do, is include "my-blog" in the URL before the post name.  I've tried things with permalinks, but that didn't work. I'm really stumped and need help with this!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if i good understand your problem, you should to go:

Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks and in "Common Settings" section select checkbox "Custom Structure" and here paste:

```
/my-blog/%postname%/
```

and save changes. Now refresh your page and go to random post and your url should be like:

https://example.com/my-blog/this-is-the-article-name

Good luck!

Comment: I think this will work!  I was playing around with something close, and changing the category base, but could not get it to work.  Thank you!!!  :D